# Overlay animations in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, animation

I've just done two animations in Photoshop, each the same size, same number of frames. The second animation has a transparent background. Is it possible to merge the two by overlaying the second onto the first?

Answer (score 2):

You can just select the two (or more) layers you want to merge and then choose "convert to smart object" -- See [this](http://forums.creativecow.net/thread/244/859800) forum thread.